# How to save a Map<String, LocalDateTime> to DynamoDB?

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to add a `Map<String, LocalDateTime>` attribute to an already existing DAO. Seems that AWS SDK doesn't know how to convert that since I keep getting this error :

`.DynamoDBMappingException: not supported; requires @DynamoDBTyped or @DynamoDBTypeConverted`

I wrote a `DynamoDBTypeConverter` to try to resolve this, but it's not showing the data in the correct format:

```
 public static class StringLocalDateTimeMapConverter
        implements DynamoDBTypeConverter<String, Map<String, LocalDateTime>> {
    @Override
    public String convert(Map<String, LocalDateTime> map) {
        try {
            if (map != null) {
                ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
                return mapper.writeValueAsString(map);
            } else {
                throw new Exception("map is empty");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error(String.format("Error converting map to Dynamo String. Reason - {%s}",
                    e.getMessage()));
            return "";
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, LocalDateTime> unconvert(String string) {
        try {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            return mapper.readValue(string, Map.class);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error(String.format("Error unconverting Dynamo String to map. Reason - {%s}",
                    e.getMessage()));
            return new HashMap<>();
        }
    }
}
```

However, this doesn't look as desired - in DDB the map ended up looking like:

```
{\"1234567890\":{\"year\":2019,\"month\":\"SEPTEMBER\",\"monthValue\":9,\"dayOfMonth\":20,\"hour\":15,\"minute\":13,\"second\":26,\"nano\":98000000,\"dayOfWeek\":\"FRIDAY\",\"dayOfYear\":263,\"chronology\":{\"calendarType\":\"iso8601\",\"id\":\"ISO\"}}}
```

I'm not sure what the best way to model this data so DDB is happy with it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

maybe parse the localDateTime to string before saving to DDB and make sure to parse it back to LocalDateTime once reading to from DDB
You can save it in ISO format

Answer (score 0):

This seem's an issue with the ObjectMapper and not with DynamoDb or with your CustomMapper.

I suppose that you use the Jackson provided by the AWS library, probably you need to add the JavaTimeModule into your project and then.

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
```

And all works fine.

This the link for the library
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype/jackson-datatype-jsr310